# Generating unique id from a collection of values

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

I would like to get ideas on how can we generate a unique id (String/Number etc) from a collection of java objects which could be of various data types like String, BigDecimal, org.joda.time.LocalDate or org.joda.time.LocalDateTime or any custom java object.

The generated id should be based on the value in the java object so that its the same id generated for two collections having same values. Something similar to sql group by clause. I want to generate a unique id from group by (col1, col2, col3) where col1, col2 and col3 could be of any data type.

Comment: Just to be clear, they must be unique, i.e. two different values must never has the same id?

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement that the generated ID value be unique, or is it acceptable if collisions are rare?

Comment: You have my permission to do that ;).  What is your question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @NPE Yes two different values should never have the same id. For e.g. If the values are - col1 = "2012-04-19 12:13:46", col2 = "2012-05-02" and col3 = "Andy", the id generated for this collection should not be the same for another collection with values col1 = "2012-04-19 12:13:45", col2 = "2012-05-02" and col3 = "Andy". (I just changed the value for col1). but it should be same for another collection with the same values.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Yes, the generated id value should be unique for a collection of values. The id generation function should return the same value for a given collection irrespective of the number of times it is invoked.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Initially I thought of using hashcode() but I found that it uses memory addresses internally for generating the hashcode of the function which does not help me. I need a unique id based on the object's value. Ideas on how would you do that?

Comment: hashCode doesn't use memory addresses as the memory address of an Object can change but the hashCode doesn't.  See my answer on how to create a unique id.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - javadocs for hash code state that "This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.". I want the integer value to be the same on every invocation of the application for a collection of values

Comment: Yes, so you can't use hashCode as it's not guaranteed to be unique even for two objects in the same JVM. e.g. many Strings have the same hashCode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21078/discussion-between-andy-dufresne-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 0):

To make a unique key if the types will not change you can use

```
String id = Arrays.toString(col1, col2, col3);
```

If you need them to be unique even with a mix and match of types, you can use Serialization which produces a binary format or

```
StringBuilder idsb = new StringBuilder();
for(Object o: arrayOfObjects) 
    idsb.append(o.getClass()).append(':').append(o).append(',');
String id = idsb.toString();
```

If you have

```
Object col1 = "2012-04-19 12:13:46", col2 = "2012-05-02", col3 = "Andy";
String key = col1+"~"+col2+"~"+col3;
```

Comment: This means that objects should have a implementation for the toString() method right? If they don't have it, the default one from Object class uses the class name and the hashcode. The default implementation of hashcode could use memory addresses which means that it could be different on every invocation of the application.

Comment: hashCode doesn't use the memory address. The memory address of an object can change and the hashCode doesn't.  The hashCode is only reasonably unique and you can have the same hashCode for two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a hashcode based approach

```
public static UUID id(List<?> list) {
    BigInteger prime = BigInteger.valueOf(31);
    BigInteger value = BigInteger.valueOf(list.size());
    for (Object element : list) {
        value = value.multiply(prime).add(BigInteger.valueOf(element.hashCode()));
        value = value.multiply(prime).add(BigInteger.valueOf(element.getClass().hashCode()));
    }
    return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(value.toByteArray());
}
```

Although this doesn't guarantee 100% uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it for any object because eg java.lang.Object has no values. For those that can be identified by values there is a solution though not simple:

Create

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
```

iterate over all fields in objects you want to create an ID on, converting them to bytes (somehow, in the worst case (field + "").getBytes()) and update the digest with these bytes

```
md.update(fieldBytes);
md.update(new int[0]);   we need separator to be safe
```

finally get your ID as BigInteger

```
  BigInteger id = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
```

You can also convert it to hex string

```
String hex = String.format("%032X", id)
```

It is practically unique. MD5 is 16 bytes. Alternatively you can use SHA-1, it is stronger, it is 20 bytes.

Comment: This means, I should make sure that the java object's override toString() method atleast (possibly through reflection) right?

Comment: Not necessarily, eg you can use apache ToStringBuilder it can make a good string for any obj for you.  But the main point is that you can hardly find an alternative to MessageDigest to solve your problem